# "Getting" the path in Linux

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I am writing a C program in Linux.  Commands like execv() require a path in the form of a C string.  Is there a command that will return the current path in the form of a C-style string?

Comment: Do you really mean the "current path" in the sense of the *current working directory* (a not very useful notion!), or rather "the path in which the current executable file lives" (a much more useful notion, but very difficult to define in full generality)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[getcwd()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html):

> #### *SYNOPSIS*
>
> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);
> ```
>
> #### *DESCRIPTION*
>
> The *getcwd()* function shall place an absolute pathname of the current working directory in the array pointed to by *buf, and return buf*. The pathname copied to the array shall contain no components that are symbolic links. The *size* argument is the size in bytes of the character array pointed to by the *buf* argument. If *buf* is a null pointer, the behavior of getcwd() is unspecified.
>
> #### *RETURN VALUE*
>
> Upon successful completion, *getcwd()* shall return the *buf* argument. Otherwise, *getcwd()* shall return a null pointer and set *errno* to indicate the error. The contents of the array pointed to by *buf* are then undefined....

Comment: Related: *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/answers-entirely-copied-though-properly-attributed/321326#321326)*

Answer (score 6):

The **path** argument to execv() is the path to the application you wish to execute, not the current working directory (which will be returned by getcwd()) or the shell search path (which will be returned by getenv("PATH")).

Depending on what you're doing, you may get more mileage out of the system() function in the C library rather than the lower-level exec() family.

Comment: `system()` is _very_ heavyweight, it launches a full shell to interpret the command line given. If you don't want to give the full path to the executable and rely on the environment's $PATH, you can use `execvp(3)`. The manual page for `exec(3)` documents a whole zoo with related functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is *not* ANSI C:

```
#include <unistd.h>

char path[MAXPATHLEN];
getcwd(path, MAXPATHLEN);
printf("pwd -> %s\n", path);
```

Comment: What is it then? How does it deviate?

Answer (score 0):

If the path can be a relative path, you should be able to use '.' or './' as the path. I'm not sure if it will work, but you could try it.

Answer (score -2):

You need to grab the environment variable PWD (present working directory).

I'm not sure what the library it is in, but it is a standard Linux header.

I was thinking of [getenv()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getenv.html) which would help if you also need to run system commands and need the various bin paths located in PATH.

Comment: Do you have a reference for P = "present" in PWD?